# aws s3 bucket getting Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, referrer-policy

so we are using an S3 bucket and when try and get a resource I get in Chrome:

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I have already applied to S3 bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

and also applied to CloudFront:

[image]

and still no luck, keep getting the error below.
I am trying to basically disable CORS and allow any origin.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this same issue and after hours of banging my head against the wall I found that something with Chrome's HTTP caching mechanism prevents the `Origin` header from being sent. This is a Chrome-specific issue as I could not reproduce it with Safari. You can check whether this is the case for you as well by toggling the "Disable Cache" option under the [Network tab of Chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucVP.png).

To force your request to ignore the cache, use appropriate `cache` option ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)). This is my final working code:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-store', // IMPORTANT: for some reason Chrome's caching doesn't send Origin
})
```

Comment: tx for that helped alot.